# Underline text font in UWP's TextBox?

Tags: uwp

I am converting an existing Windows control to UWP. I don't see a way to have underline font style in UWP's TextBox control.

Am I missing something basic? Or should I forget TextBox and use RichEditBox (which would be a massive overkill for my purposes)?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to edit the template style of the textbox to include underline in it.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you mean the one from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396? Which particular element do I need to edit?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to do this but I think u hve to edit the TextBlock called "GlpyhElement" and somehow put underline on it with Underline tag : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.underline

Comment: Hmm.. TextBox or TextBlock? If it's TextBlock it's as easy as setting up the property TextDecoration to Underline

Comment: @Mac - TextBox. It needs to look and behave like a regular single line edit control.

Comment: If only one font style is expected, using `RichEditBox` is not an overkill - it won't lower code readability, it won't impact app performance - right?

Comment: Maybe you could use the border to mimic the underline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something basic? Or should I forget TextBox and use RichEditBox (which would be a massive overkill for my purposes)?

You could use the core text APIs in the [Windows.UI.Text.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn958238) namespace to make your own custom input control.

You just need to use some general UWP control(e.g, textblock, stackpanel, border etc) to make a input control (you could call it your own custom textbox) which has underline when you input text in it.

Here's a UWP official [Custom Edit Control sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomEditControl). I just specified the `TextDecorations` property value for the `TextBlock` in 'CustomEditControl.xaml', then, I achieved your target.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="BorderPanel" BorderThickness="4" Background="White">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock x:Name="BeforeSelectionText" Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CaretText" Text="&#xe12b;" Foreground="Blue" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
            <Border Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock x:Name="SelectionText" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock x:Name="AfterSelectionText" Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: This sort of  kind of works. But looks extremely ugly visually and sucks pretty badly functionality wise compared to a regular TextBox. I just find it incredible that such a simple thing that I did not think twice about back in the Windows 3.0 days is impossible in the brave new UWP world...

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the border to the default style, but I think that's gonna be a tough one, you can use RichEditBox for now while working on overriding the default style through creating a new style resource, I understand that RichEditBox is not designed for accepting inputs from the user but I think it wouldn't hurt that much with the performance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/text-controls